# How to show popup in AngularJS app using bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, popup, angular-ui

I need to show 4-5 popup in a view. As of now i am using bootstrap to show the popup. But my problem is that my html page became heavy, there is page's own content and 5 popup's content. I want to move each popup's content in different html page. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "popup" you mean modal window. I agree with Aditya above, [using the angular-ui modal  service](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) is very good. However, unlike the suggestion to use ng-include, I recommend using the modal's built-in "templateUrl" to keep the markup in a separate file. I have used this in my projects and it works well.

Comment: Thanks Barnabas, I also followed same approach and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular ui modal windows

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

for seperating the templates, in the script you can use `<div data-ng-include="'/templte/modal.html'"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

**ng-include=""** is good if you use one dialog with multiple pages or tabs. Changing only the html name works fine and make it simple. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-include="getCurrentPage()"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
scope.getCurrentPage = function(){
    return "path/to/html" + scope.pageId + ".html";
};
```

However, for your current scenario, I would recommend Barnabas Kendall's way. I can share what I have used. I created a single service for a group of modals.

**Angular Module**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

**Service (for group of modals)**

```
app.service('ModalDialogs', function ($modal) {
    return {
        modalDialog1: modalDialog1,
        modalDialog2: modalDialog2
    };

    var modalDialog1 = function (size, param1, param2) {
        var ControllerForDialog1 = function (scope, modalInstance, param1, param2) {
            scope.cancel = function () {
                modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };

            // todo
        };

        return $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'path/to/dialog1.html',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                param1: function () {
                    return param1 + param2;
                },
                param2: function () {
                    return "this can be any value";
                }
            },
            controller: ControllerForDialog1
        });
    };

    var modalDialog2 = function (size, param1) {
        var ControllerForDialog2 = function (scope, modalInstance, anotherParam) {
            scope.cancel = function () {
                modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };

            // todo
        };

        return $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'path/to/dialog2.html',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                anotherParam: function () {
                    return "this can be any value" + param1;
                }
            },
            controller: ControllerForDialog2
        });
    };
});
```

**Usages**

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, ModalDialogs){
    ModalDialogs.modalDialog2('lg', 'YourName');
});
```